# How to Dependency Inject database in Play 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, playframework-2.5

I'm migrating from play 2.3 to 2.5

Originally I have "DAOFactory" object

```
object DAOFactory {
  def categoryDAO: CategoryDAO =  AnormCategoryDAO

  def itemDAO: ItemDAO = AnormItemDAO

  def bidDAO: BidDAO = AnormBidDAO

  def userDAO: UserDAO = AnormUserDAO

  def feedStatsDAO: FeedStatsDAO = AnormFeedStatsDAO
}
```

and let's take "AnormCategoryDAO" as a example, and I have to change the "object" into a "Class"

```
object AnormCategoryDAO extends CategoryDAO {
  val category = {
    int("id") ~ str("display_name") ~ str("url_name") map {
      case id~displayName~urlName => Category(id, displayName, urlName)
    }
  }

  def create(displayName: String, urlName: String) = DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    SQL("INSERT INTO category(display_name, url_name) VALUES({displayName}, {urlName})").on(
      'displayName -> displayName, 'urlName -> urlName).executeUpdate()
  }

  def findById(id: Int): Option[Category] = DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    SQL("SELECT * FROM category WHERE id = {id}").on('id -> id).as(category singleOpt)
  }

  def findByName(urlName: String): Option[Category] = DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    SQL("SELECT * FROM category WHERE url_name = {urlName}").on('urlName -> urlName).as(category singleOpt)
  }

  def all(): List[Category] = DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    SQL("SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY display_name").as(category *)
  }
}
```

So I changed the OBJECT to CLASS and annotated with SINGLETON as below, and I changed "DB.withConnection" to "db.withConnection"

```
@Singleton
class AnormCategoryDAO @Inject()(db: Database) extends CategoryDAO {
  val category = {
    int("id") ~ str("display_name") ~ str("url_name") map {
      case id~displayName~urlName => Category(id, displayName, urlName)
    }
  }

...
```

Now, "AnormCategoryDAO" is a Class. So I need to figure out a way to instantiate it with a default database. 
But I don't know how to instantiate it.

```
object DAOFactory {
  //def categoryDAO: CategoryDAO = AnormCategoryDAO

  def userDAO: UserDAO = AnormUserDAO

  def itemDAO: ItemDAO = AnormItemDAO
}
```

The question is, how do I inject the database and instantiate it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to use guice or similar to di. with compile time di I can achieve that by using something like:

```
import play.api.db.slick.{DbName, SlickComponents}

trait TablesComponents extends BaseComponent with SlickComponents {

  lazy val dbConf = api.dbConfig[JdbcProfile](DbName("default"))

  lazy val myTable = new MyTable(dbConf.db)
  lazy val otherTable = new OtherTable(dbConf.db)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You either have the dependency that is to be injected ready, in which case you may call `new AnormCategoryDAO(myDb)` directly, or you inject the `AnormCategoryDAO` wherever it is required (this could mean that dependency injection propagates all the way to the controllers, which are instantiated by Play).

For Example:

```
class CategoryService @Inject() (categoryDao: CategoryDAO) {
  def findAll() = categoryDao.findAll()
}
```

Note that in this example, I used the abstract type `CategoryDAO` to refer to the `categoryDAO`. For this, you'll have to tell the dependency injection framework (typically Guice) which concreate class it should inject (binding). Alternatively, you could depend on `AnormCategoryDAO` directly.

How you can define custom bindings is documented here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection

Note that there is an alternative approach to dependency injection named compile time: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCompileTimeDependencyInjection

Comment: I had read this documentation you passed me, but I couldn't understand well, now I'm reading guice documentation and I think I'm understanding a little. After I have read this, I come again and let a comment, thank you

Comment: @Augusto if you're not familiar with dependency injection, I recommend to this talk from the creator of guice: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFXhXZnmEQM

Comment: Yet I'm understanding this subject. I took the DI project from playframework to understand and get to know how to assemble. https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-compile-di-with-tests